# How to concatenate values from multiple rows with the same id to a comma separated with unique id

Tags: php, file, csv

I have a CSV file, name it `data.csv`, that looks like this:

```
id,position,data
1,1,Data text
1,2,Data text 2
1,3,Data text 3
2,1,Data text x
2,2,Data text y
```

What I need is to concatenate the values in the field `data` in a single one for all the rows with the same `id`. Then, print those newly obtained rows in another CSV file.

I managed to arrange the values in an array, but at the conversion to the CSV file it saves only one of them.

Here is my code

```
$file = 'data.csv';
$tsvFile = new SplFileObject($file);
$tsvFile->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$tsvFile->setCsvControl(",");

foreach ($tsvFile as $line => $row) {
    if ($line > 0) {
            $newData[$row[0]] = array('id'=>$row[0], 'position'=>$row[1], 'data'=>$row[2]);
            $newData[$row[1]] = $row[2];
    }
}
//
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newData);
//
$fp = fopen('data2.csv', 'w');
foreach ($newData as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

At the end, the resulting CSV file should look like this:

```
id,data
"1","Data text, Data text 1, Data text 2"
"2","Data text x, Data text y"
```

Comment: Just to get thing straight: you have a CSV (`data.csv`) that look like the first highlighted block, and you want parse it in another CSV file that looks like the last highlighted block?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you could do what you ask in an easier way.

I just used `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` functions to handle the extraction and insertion of a well formed and well formatted row from/to file.

```
$output = array();

if ($in_handle = fopen('data.csv', 'r')) {
    // discard the first line, the one with the names of the fields
    $input = fgetcsv($in_handle);

    // get an array out of a row from the file data.csv
    while ($input = fgetcsv($in_handle)) {
        // create an array with only the needed fields
        $current_row = array(
            'id' => $input[0],
            'data' => $input[2]
        );

        if (array_key_exists($current_row['id'], $output)) {
            $output[$current_row['id']]['data'] .= ' ' . $current_row['data'];
        } else {
            $output[$current_row['id']] = $current_row;
        }
    }

    fclose($in_handle);

    if ($out_handle = fopen('new_file.csv', 'w')) {
        // recreate the first line of the file deleted before
        $fields_names = array('id', 'data');
        fputcsv($out_handle, $fields_names);

        // begins at 1 because there isn't any value before
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($output); ++$i)
            fputcsv($out_handle, $output[$i]);
    }

    fclose($out_handle);
}
```

Here's the input I used to test the script:

```
id,position,data
1,1,first string
1,2,second string
1,3,third string
2,1,fourth string
2,2,fifth string
```

And here's the output file i obtained:

```
id,data
1,"first string second string third string"
2,"fourth string fifth string"
```

As you can see, the `data` part of the rows is now quoted. That's just the way standard CSV handles strings.

Comment: it return Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Comment: It __is__ an array. Just check your file and the `for` counter. I made `$i` starting from `1` because there wasn't index before of it, as said in the comment above the loop. Now you have to adapt it to your code.