# CSV file multilple line with same ID

Tags: php, xml, csv, concatenation

I've got a CSV file with product information for a e-commerce platform. The CSV file contains multiple rows with same product ID and multiple description. Each value is seperated by "^" instead of comma. 
What i want to achieve is to combine these multiple rows into one and comma seperated and have only 1 row with the product information. So my problem is to combine multiple rows with same attribute.

**Here is the formating of the file today**

```
productID^Element^Value<br>
id01^Status^01<br>
id01^edited^2016-01-01<br>
id01^Longdesc^Here goes the description<br>
id01^Longdesc^Here is the second line of description<br>
id01^longdesc^And the third row<br>
id01^image^Link to image 1<br>
```

**This is what i'm looking for to achieve:**

```
ID01, 2016-01-01, Here goes the description Here is the second line of description And the third row, link to image
```

The other idea is to put structure to an nice XML file.

Hope you guys have some good solutions for this and can help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: That seems like a simple enough problem - loop through the lines, parse them, and re-print them whichever way you like. What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610886/how-to-concatenate-values-from-multiple-rows-with-the-same-id-to-a-comma-separat  but can't get the longdescription to combine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to bellow code. I am sure this code will work fine.

```
public function import_product_from_csv() {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
        $fh = fopen('your_csv_file.csv', 'r');
        fgets($fh, 4096);

        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $buffer = fgets($fh, 4096);
            $arrTemp = explode('^',$buffer);

            if($arrTemp[0] != "") {
                $data = array(
                    'productID' => $arrTemp[0], // codice provincia
                    'Element' => $arrTemp[1], //codice comune
                    'Value' => $arrTemp[2] //denominazione
                );
                $sql_query = "insert into table_name (productID, Element, Value) values ('".$arrTemp[0]."', '".$arrTemp[1]."', '".$arrTemp[2]."')";
                mysql_query($sql_query);
            }

            /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($arrTemp);
            echo "</pre>";*/
        }
        fclose($fh);
        echo "Uploaded";
    }
```

Happy code...